# Get a value from <link>

Tags: javascript

Friends, I would like to get the **value** of  or just know if it exists, does anyone have an idea?

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stacks.css?v=f956aeec157c" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="primary.css?v=f68ca0e24c3b" >

</head>

<body>

 
    <link extension-installed="0318648714777">


<p>Click the button to find out how many <link> elements.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("link");

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.length;
}
</script>
</pre>
```

unfortunately it counts all  page

Comment: You can try getting it by attribute **extension-installed**, if its common for all your links.. Something like `document.querySelectorAll('[extension-installed]');`

Comment: the value of what exactly?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try getting it by attribute **extension-installed**, if its common for all your links.. Something like `document.querySelectorAll('[extension-installed]');`

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stacks.css?v=f956aeec157c">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="primary.css?v=f68ca0e24c3b">

</head>

<body>


  <link extension-installed="0318648714777">


  <p>Click the button to find out how many
    <link> elements.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.querySelectorAll('[extension-installed]');

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.length;
    }
  </script>
  </pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelector` with the selector string `body > link` to find a `<link>` directly inside the body:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const link = document.querySelector('body > link');
  console.log(link);
  console.log(link.getAttribute('extension-installed'));
}
```

```css
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stacks.css?v=f956aeec157c">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="primary.css?v=f68ca0e24c3b">

<style>
```

```html
<link extension-installed="0318648714777">


<p>Click the button to find out how many
  <link> elements.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

If it's not a direct child of the body, use `body link` instead, to get a link anywhere inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll("link")`. It will give the nodelist containing all the link elements

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stacks.css?v=f956aeec157c" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="primary.css?v=f68ca0e24c3b" >

</head>

<body>


    <link extension-installed="0318648714777">


<p>Click the button to find out how many link elements.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("link");

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.length;
}
</script>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are searching the elements with  tag:

```
  document.getElementsByTagName("link");
```

They are actually four there:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stacks.css?v=f956aeec157c"></link>,
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="primary.css?v=f68ca0e24c3b"></link>,
<link extension-installed="0318648714777"></link>,
<link></link>
```

If you need specific link, try using an id with it and select by ID:

```
<link extension-installed="0318648714777" id="myLink"></link>

var x = document.getElementsById("myLink");
```

Or simply try to find link with attribute `extension-installed`

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('[extension-installed]');
```